# Total logical reads per database on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to get the total running logical reads\writes per database from last restart?  Trying to monitor what dbs are most used and if that changes over time.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a query like this, with the caveat that it will also track backup activity as reads. I'm also not aware of a DMV that tracks logical reads in the way you want.

To account for the backups caveat, you may want to stick it in an Agent Job and log it to a table at the beginning and end of working periods, or some other cadence that makes sense.

If you have [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15) enabled on all of your databases, you could take a daily snapshot of [runtime_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-runtime-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get closer to the truth. But that's a big if, and depending on your settings it may not capture all query activity.

```
SELECT
    run_date = 
        GETDATE(),
    days_up = 
        DATEDIFF
        (
            DAY,
            DATEADD
            (
                MILLISECOND,
                -vfs.sample_ms,
                GETDATE()
            ),
            GETDATE()
        ),
    database_name = 
        DB_NAME(vfs.database_id),
    drive = 
        LEFT
        (
            mf.physical_name, 
            1
        ),
    mf.physical_name,
    size_on_disk_mb = 
        vfs.size_on_disk_bytes / 1024 / 1024.,
    read_latency = 
        (vfs.io_stall_read_ms 
            / NULLIF(vfs.num_of_reads, 0)),
    mb_read = 
        vfs.num_of_bytes_read 
            / 1000000.,
    avg_mb_per_read =     
        (vfs.num_of_bytes_read 
            / NULLIF(vfs.num_of_reads, 0)) / 1000000.,
    avg_read_stall = 
        vfs.num_of_reads 
            / NULLIF(vfs.io_stall_read_ms, 0),
    write_latency = 
        (vfs.io_stall_write_ms 
            / NULLIF(vfs.num_of_writes, 0)),
    mb_written =
        vfs.num_of_bytes_written / 1000000.,
   avg_mb_per_write = 
       (vfs.num_of_bytes_written 
           / NULLIF(vfs.num_of_writes, 0)) / 1000000.,
    avg_write_stall = 
        vfs.num_of_writes
            / NULLIF(vfs.io_stall_write_ms, 0)
FROM sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(NULL, NULL) AS vfs
JOIN sys.master_files AS mf
    ON  vfs.database_id = mf.database_id
    AND vfs.file_id = mf.file_id
ORDER BY size_on_disk_mb DESC;
```

Comment: Note `sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats.num_of_reads` tracks "Physical IO", reads from the files to the page cache, not "Logical IO", which is reads from the page cache.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft yeah, there's just not a great solution for what they're looking for ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a DMV that tracks logical IO, but this is one of the database-level metrics you can derive with reasonable accuracy by tracking session_logout.  This event misses long-lived connections and connections that change between databases.  But for many scenarios is pretty accurate.  EG

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [session_logout] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.logout(
    ACTION(sqlserver.database_id))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'session_logout')
go
```

captures data like

[image]